# Google Mini - How to open the case?

Tags: search

I have a Google Mini and I cannot open the case? It seems to be a simple case, but I cannot figure it out. I removed the two screws in the back and I am expecting to slide the top back and it would remove like 1,000 other servers I have that do this.

I can't get it.

Does anyone know how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an [article from AnandTech](https://www.anandtech.com/show/1781/3) where they open up the Google mini.  There's a couple of awkward screws in the front to remove that have no usable screwhead...
[image]

Comment: @izzy - Thank you, I googled for an hour and did not find this! What did you search for?

Comment: @Indie - Nuts - first search, fourth result! Searched for *open case google mini*, 4th link, and followed the trail from there. Fear the Google-Fu ;)

Comment: @izzy - I am in, looks awesome, do you have a tutorial to remove/add hard a hard drive?

Comment: Depends on the chassis, but it's all pretty standard stuff if you've worked with servers before...

Comment: @izzy - I have 1,000 servers and none are like this. It looks like the front is riveted on? so I can't easily take it off to expose the front drive bays

Comment: If you have a thousand servers, why are you trying to prise open a Google Mini device to host your website on?